# Calling MainWindow method from a UserControl class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a C# WPF application where the `MainWindow` XAML defines a series of menu tabs.

I have a `UserControl` class for license settings that needs to toggle the visibility of these tabs based on certain activities.

My first attempt was to create a public method in `MainWindow` and call it from the `UserControl` class.

```
Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
mainWindow.myPublicMethod();
```

This doesn't work because my method isn't defined in the `Window` class.

I then tried to cast it to a `MainWindow` object:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
mainWindow.myPublicMethod();
```

This doesn't work because it cannot find the type `MainWindow` since it is in a different project.

I tried to add a reference to that project but it complains about a circular dependency.

Is there a recommended way of accomplishing what I need to do?

### Update

**UserControl class code**

```
public event EventHandler licenseActivated;

protected void onLicenseActivated()
{
  var handler = licenseActivated;

  if (handler != null)
  {
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml code**

Added event at the bottom right before the closing tag

```
<telerik:RadTabControl Grid.Row="0" Margin="1,1,1,0" Background="White" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ShellTabItemStyleMain}"
        x:Name="ContentGrid" HeaderBackground="{StaticResource HeaderBackground1}" SelectionChanged="ContentGrid_SelectionChanged" 
        BorderThickness="0">
    
    <telerik:RadTabItem Name="ModelCatalogTab" MouseDown="ModelCatalogTab_MouseDown" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,4" x:Name="MyModelsImage" Source="{StaticResource MyImgModelsBlue}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,4">My Models</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
            <uc:ucwpfCatalog x:Name="ModelCatalog" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="{StaticResource defaultForeground}"/>
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
    <telerik:RadTabItem Name="DataSetTab" IsEnabled="False"  Foreground="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" MouseDown="DataSetTab_MouseDown" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,4" x:Name="MyDataSetImage" Source="{StaticResource MyImgDataSetGray}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,4">Data</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
           
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
    <telerik:RadTabItem Name="VariablesTab" IsEnabled="False"  Foreground="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" MouseDown="VariablesTab_MouseDown" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,4" x:Name="MyVariablesImage" Source="{StaticResource MyImgVariablesGray}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,4">Variables</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
           
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
    <telerik:RadTabItem Name="ModelBuildingTab" IsEnabled="False"  Foreground="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" MouseDown="ModelBuildingTab_MouseDown" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,4" x:Name="MyModelBuildImage" Source="{StaticResource MyImgModelingGray}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,4">Predictive Modeling</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
            <ucmb:ucwpfModelBuilding x:Name="ModelBuilding" Margin="-10,-5,-12,-12" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Foreground="{StaticResource defaultForeground}"/>
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
    <telerik:RadTabItem Name="ClusteringTab" IsEnabled="False"  Foreground="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" MouseDown="ClusteringTab_MouseDown" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,4" x:Name="MyClusteringImage" Source="{StaticResource MyImgClustersGray}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,4">Clustering</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
           
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
    <telerik:RadTabItem Name="LogsViewerTab" IsEnabled="False"  Foreground="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" MouseDown="LogsViewerTab_MouseDown" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,4" x:Name="MyLogsImage" Source="{StaticResource MyImgLogsGray}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,4">Logs</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
           
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
    <telerik:RadTabItem Name="AppSettingsTab" MouseDown="AppSettingsTab_MouseDown" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,0,4" x:Name="MyOptionsImage" Source="{StaticResource MyImgSettingsBlue}"  />
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,4">Settings</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
        </telerik:RadTabItem.Header>
           
    </telerik:RadTabItem>
    <uc:ucwpfAppOptions licenseActivated="AppOptions_LicenseActivated" />
</telerik:RadTabControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void AppOptions_LicenseActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  enableMenuTab(ModelCatalogTab);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for an event.

Using an event allows *any* parent to use this usercontrol for its own purposes, not just your particular MainWindow class. You can use the usercontrol in other applications, or elsewhere in this application. We call this "loose coupling".

UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
public event EventHandler ThingHappened;

protected void OnThingHappened()
{
    var handler = ThingHappened;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public void SomeRandomMethod()
{
    DoStuff();

    OnThingHappened();

    DoOtherStuff();
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<myns:UserControl1 ThingHappened="UserControl1_ThingHappened" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void UserControl1_ThingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myPublicMethod();
}
```

Comment: `Foobar.DoParentThing = myPublicMethod();` doesn't compile.  And you should use an actual event, rather than just a public delegate property, when you conceptually have an event; this is literally exactly what events are for.

Comment: @Servy Fixed typo, thanks. Fair enough point about the event.

Comment: Just watch out for possible memory leaks, where the owner of the event holds a reference to the target and prevents the garbage collector from freeing it.  This can be a particularly troublesome in WPF because of the way things can be virtualized.  I think in this case you will be safe, since the `UserControl` holds the reference to the `Window` that contains it, they both have the same life-time.  If you ever *do* run in to problems though, look to the [Weak Event Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns) to fix it.

Comment: Thanks.   I implemented this code but it appears that member is always null.  Perhaps I am not putting the MainWindow.xaml code in the correct location.

Comment: @A_B What member is always null?

Comment: @EdPlunkett  var member = ThingHappened;

Comment: @A_B Ahhh, OK. Sorry. I meant to type `handler` there; no idea how I made it `member`. Hmm. That would be because nobody's handling the event. How are you setting up the event handler in MainWindow? In XAML as I did it? Can you add that part to your question?

Comment: @EdPlunkett  Can I add the XAML code anywhere or does it have to be in a specific location in the document?

Comment: @A_B The end would be great. Just put `##Update` in front of it at the very end of your question.

Comment: Thanks. Is the UserControl visible? Is it displayed in a TabItem? What you've got there looks 100% correct with the potential exception of where the usercontrol is in the XAML. I don't have the Telerik controls so I can't test, but just for laughs I'd try putting it someplace where there's no question that it's a regular visual child.